# Decide if a formula is logically true without a given structure

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

For instance the formula:

> $\forall x\exists y :\text{GreaterThan}(y, x)$

Which indicates that $x$ is greater than $y$. Does it suffice to find one structure where this statement is untrue to prove that the statement is logically untrue?

An example would be then: $D = \{n | n \in\mathbb N\}$
So that

> $\forall x\exists y :\text{GreaterThan}(y, 0)$

makes the formula untrue?

In case you change the interpretation of $\text{GreaterThan}$ to $y$ is greater than $x$, the formula becomes true, right?

Comment: What do you mean by _logically true_?

Comment: @Ansar, the terminology isn't explain really well in the text book. But I assume logically true == tautology, while true == true in a certain structure.

Comment: GreaterThan seems to be a binary predicate, right? Is there anything else we know about GreaterThan?

Comment: "logically untrue" sounds like it should mean it *can't* be true (in other words its negation is true in all interpretations). So it means something different from "not logically true." (Also, on a side note, "logically true" is not really a standard terminology... usually we say 'valid'.)

Comment: If "logically true" means *valid*, i.e. true in every interpretation, then YES, to show that the formula is **not** valid it is enough to find a suitable interpretation that falsifies it.

Comment: Obviously the formula $\forall x \exists y P(y,x)$ is not valid. Consider "y is son of x" as interpretation for $P$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen the text book is in Dutch, the corresponding term for the Dutch word is "true", my bad.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Considering we have GreaterThan with an interpretation given to it, does the interpretation change with a new structure. So for my example GreaterThan(y,x), could I come up with a structure where GreaterThan(y,x) means y is son of x?

Comment: An interpretation is a domain with suitable "meaning" for the symbols of the language; so, what do you mean with a "given interpretation with a new structure" ?

Comment: So that in one structure, GreaterThan(x,y) is interpretated as x is greater than y, and in another x is son of y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If **logically true** means **tautology** and **logically untrue** means **not a tautology** then yes, it suffices to find one such structure. A formula $A$ in $L$ which is a tautology is *true* in any structure for $L$. This immediately follows from the definition of **tautology** (I'm using Shoenfield's terminology). However, it is easier to use the definition directly.

P.S.  Also keep in mind that $\exists y :\text{GreaterThan}(y, 0)$ and  $\text{GreaterThan}(y, 0)$ are not equivalent. You probably meant the first one in the second highlighted line.

Comment: I forgot my quantifiers whoops. Also, could GreaterThan(y,x) be interpretated in a structure as y is a son of x, despite the name?

Comment: @LLScheme Of course, GreaterThan is a binary predicate symbol and "_ is a son of _" is a binary predicate.  That's all that matters. I believe you should revise the terminology.